# Path to mysqldump on Azure VM?

Tags: mysql, backup, azure

I've set up a VM running MySQL Server (Community Edition) on Azure. My CMS ([Perch](http://grabaperch.com)) has a backup module, which uses mysqldump to back up the database. However, the default options don't seem to be compatible with the way MySQL works on Azure.

Does anyone have experience working with MySQL as a VM in Azure, and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: what do you mean by default options? are you able to ssh to this machine and run mysqldump? maybe the only problem is that it's not in the PATH.

Comment: By default options, I mean that the CMS is (I believe) trying to connect to localhost's mysqldump. The database isn't running on the same (virtual) machine as the website, so localhost isn't a valid path. The VM has its own cloudapp.net endpoint for MySQL connections, so I'm assuming I need to start with that, but beyond that I'm not sure where to go.

Comment: Is your cms installed and working or do you still have to make the connection with the DB to install? usually the cms deployment is made togheter with the DB since essencial users and tables need to be created.

Comment: The CMS is up and running. I'm connecting to the database using the VM's external cloudapp.net address and relevant port number. What I can't do - and what the question is about - is determine how to access mysqldump from this connection.